# Chef - restarting due to auto-encryption mechanism

Tags: chef-infra, devops

We have an issue with Chef in that it restarts unnecessarily.  We schedule chef-client to run every 1 5 minutes. However, a restart of processes and the app occurs every time, even when the user has not made changes.

The reason for this is we have a proprietary app we are automating that has a mechanism whereby it encrypts a plain text password in a config file, so every time chef runs, it sees a difference in the config file it generates from the template (unencrypted string), and the currently deployed config file (that this app has touched after chef and encrypted the text).

The app team does touch this file frequently in other places so ignoring that file completely is not ideal. However, looking for options from others who may have faced the same issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would probably be to make your own resource that knows how to check for the existing encrypted blob, pull it out of the file, and then include it in the rendered template so it will be exactly the same. You could build a custom resource for this, or just use a `ruby_block` resource to parse out the file (regex most likely, if the format isn't too terrible).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is typical with apps that not only read but also update configuration files. This is common. Password encryption is one reason but there are others.

The way I "silence" Chef is to create a separate, extra, shadow configuration file. If for example the config file is `/opt/app/config.xml` I create `/opt/app/config.xml.chef`. All data that I put in the `config.xml` using Chef I also put in `config.xml.chef`.

The `notifies` I move from the original config file  to the shadow config `config.xml.chef`

```
template "/opt/app/config.xml.chef" do
  ...
  notifies :reload, 'service[myapp]', :delayed
end
```

In the resource for the original config I put a reminder.

```
template "/opt/app/config.xml" do
  ...
  # no notifies here, use shadow config file
end
```